# What does this env var mean? "_=/usr/bin/kdeinit"

Tags: vim, environment-variables

```
cshell> env 
...
_=/usr/bin/kdeinit
```

I suspect this variable slows down vim startup. Now I have to launch 'vim -X', otherwise it takes 6 seconds to start vim.

I cannot google it, since most answers related to "env var underscore' explain  "$_", which is not what I want.

Comment: But `$_` *is* how you'd access it...?

Comment: $_ is the special variable that stores last command, is it the `_` in `env`

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing. Just like how you use $PATH to access the environment variable `PATH`. I don't know _why_ shells tend to export $_ to the environment, but they do. So when the '/usr/bin/kdeinit' shellscript ran, it exported that.

Comment: @YaoJin: It's actually the last parameter of the last command. For example, this will echo "three": `true one two three; echo $_`

Comment: Thank you all. I understand it now. It is the last command after shell starts;

Answer (score 2):

**Easy answer with *csh***

If you only worry about C Shell, that's easy. It is the command line of the last command executed. See [*Variable substitution*](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Variable_substitution.html) in the [*tcsh* documentation](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/top.html)

**Easy answer with *bash***

In Bash, the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) in the chapter [*Special Parameters*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html) tell us the following:

> At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname used to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in the environment or argument list. Subsequently, expands to the last argument to the previous command, after expansion. Also set to the full pathname used to invoke each command executed and placed in the environment exported to that command. When checking mail, this parameter holds the name of the mail file.

So in *bash*, it's usually the last argument to the previous command. *Usually...*

**Complex answer with both *bash* and *csh***

In your case, the software *kdeinit* was called from a Bash shell. Before executing *kdeinit*, the full pathname of the command (*/usr/bin/kdeinit*) was copied by *bash* in the underscore environment variable as per the explication below. The software *kdeinit* initialized your graphical environment, propagating this environment variable to every child processes. Your C Shell terminal therefore inherited that environment variable.

When you're in that C Shell, the confusion is between the shell variable *$_* and the environment variable *_*. In C Shell, when you use the *$name* construct, it output the the shell variable or the environment variable if the shell variable doesn't exist. In this case, they both exist and are different. The environment variable (as shown by the command *env*) will always remind the same  */usr/bin/kdeinit* value while the shell variable will keep changing to show the last command executed.

Comment: As for your issue with vim, if you want to test running vim without that environment variable, executing the following command: *env -u _*